# the whole is wide in one part?

Tags: semantics

> Bicycles are parked where the sidewalk is wide.

> The sidewalk is wide here.

If I want to say *bicycles are parked on the wide part of the sidewalk* or *this part of the sidewalk is wide*, are they correct?

Comment: What is the wide part of a sidewalk??

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are correct.

But few people would use two sentences to convey that information when it's more natural to say:

**Bicycles are parked here where the sidewalk is wide/wider/widest**.